# What is the Difference Between Git Cherry-Pick and Git Revert?

Tags: git, git-revert, git-cherry-pick

I still find the behavior of git revert somewhat confusing. After significant pain and misunderstanding, I learnt that git revert *negates* a particular commit rather than reverting *to*  that commit. I have not used git cherry-pick so far.

Can you elaborate on each of these two git commands? When and how do you prefer to use them?

Comment: Please first try to search Internet before requesting to duplicate documentation here. Here you have result from first page of Google results for 'git commands' search: quick-ref http://gitref.org/ and full commands reference http://git-scm.com/book/commands - my comment refer to original question before first edit "can you elaborate on each git command...", sorry if your intention was what Emil fixed in his edit.

Comment: @MBO: Yes my original question was: "Can you elaborate on each git command and when and how do you prefer to use it?" I have looked at google searches multiple times and do have 4 books on git. Using git revert was genuinely painful initially since for 1-2 months I understood it to mean reverting TO a particular commit and I could not understand the bizarre behavior it produced. I still find it a little confusing specially if there are interim commits between HEAD and the commit I am reverting OUT of.

Answer (score 10):

`git cherry-pick` is like "Convert the specified commit into a patch and apply this patch here".

`git revert` is like "Convert the specified commit into a patch, 'invert' this patch (like in `patch -R`) and apply it here".

Both commands can lead to conflicts.

Cherry-pick is used on unmerged (not reachable by parent links from current commit) commits. Revert is typically used on merged commits.

Undoing a revert commit requires making another revert commit (leading to commit messages like "Revert of 'Revert of ...'"), not cherry-picking reverted commit (as it is considered already merged).